# Android - Google Maps NullPointer in onResume

Tags: android, google-maps

I am having some random crashes in `super.onResume` with Google maps. It only happens in debug mode, not in production. It is weird how the map is added to the fragment (not coded by myself), but it was working properly before. Just some day started to crash. Below you can see the error and the code. I would really appreciate some help!

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.b (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onResume (Unknown Source)
com.xxxx.xxxx.Fragments.FragmentMap.onResume (FragmentMap.java:983)
com.xxxx.xxxx.Fragments.FragmentMap.onConnected(FragmentMap.java:2667)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk (Unknown Source)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

And this is the Fragment where is painting the Map:

```
public class FragmentMap extends MapFragment implements LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {
GoogleMap map;
GoogleApiClient 
{...}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//Instantiate here all not view objects (Fragments good practices)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        // Building the GoogleApi client
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();
        checkLocationSettings();

    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    map = this.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mapView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());

    if (condition1) {
        View firstOverlay = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_map_layout, null);
        rl.addView(mapView);
        rl.addView(firstOverlay);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    } else {
        View srcvAddress = inflater.inflate(R.layout.address_finder, null);
        rl.addView(mapView);
        rl.addView(srcvAddress);
    }

    return rl;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); <----------------------- **HERE CRASHES!!**
    stopUpdatePositionService();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
       {...}
    }
}

/**
 * Creating google api client object
 */
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

 /**
 * Stopping location updates
 */
private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

/**
 * Google api callback methods
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    // Once connected with google api, get the location
    onResume();
    //displayLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

/**
 * Creating location request object
 */
private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously you shouldn't call fragment's lifecycle  callbacks by yourself ...

Comment: Is not the best practice but is not the problem

Comment: *Is not the best practice but is not the problem* yes, it is ... you are telling fragment that it is in resume state while it isn't ... also stacktrace shows that it is a problem

Comment: Just moving all the code inside onResume to another function and call that function from onConnected and same error. Check @prabhat yadav solution

Comment: As I said, "It is weird how the map is added to the fragment (not coded by myself)", the code is a mesh. However, it is easier in this case (in terms of time) to "fix" the mesh than recreate everything from the beginning. It doesn't make sense at all even that I have to call getChildFragmentManager inside the MapFragment but it just simply works. The question is why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

map=this.getmap();---> might be the problem
instead try this

```
map= ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();//where R.id.map is google map fragment
```

Comment: The point is that is not defined anywhere the map. It is just called like this:  manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, FragmentMap.newInstance(userData)).commit();

Comment: Btw, adding the fragment to the layout and adding that line also crashes at that line (R.id.map is defined): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.xxx.xxx.Fragments.FragmentMap.onActivityCreated(FragmentMap.java:334)

Comment: Ok, after some changes, finally solved changing getFragmentManager by getChildFragmentManager. I do not understand that logic being inside FragmentMap, but it just works! thanks @prabhat

Answer (score 0):

Note for future: Forget about getMap. It is already deprecated. When I moved everything to the new getMapAsync it is working everything fine